# How to align/set/put/style two div next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have some problem with my CSS and HTML. I can't style the 2 footer items to be on the same line. Is there something wrong with how I have my divs and styles?

Suggestion to make better code is very welcome. I have tried float, inline-block.

```css
/*footer*/
footer {
  color:white;
  background-color: #c2b180;
}
.button-social {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sameline.block {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<footer>
  <div class="sameline.block">
  <div class="about-this-page">
      <h3>About this page</h3>
      <p>Made by Duy Ta</p>
  </div>
    <div class="around-the-web">
      <h3>Around the Web</h3>
       <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
       <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
       <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-below">qlip © 
    <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>. All Rights Reversed
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify float for right elements also

```
#footer-below {float: right; width: 50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A class name can't contain a `dot`.

So change it to for example `samelineblock`

Then select the divs that are a direct child of that element and give them an `inline-block`.

You can adjust the width by setting it.

```css
/*footer*/

footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #c2b180;
}

.button-social {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.samelineblock>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<footer>
  <div class="samelineblock">
    <div class="about-this-page">
      <h3>About this page</h3>
      <p>Made by Duy Ta</p>
    </div>
    <div class="around-the-web">
      <h3>Around the Web</h3>
      <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
      <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
      <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-below">qlip ©
    <script>
      document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
    </script>. All Rights Reversed
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use dots to name the classes. Then in order to set two elements side by side you need to set their float to left, not the container.
So in your example rename *sameline.block* to *samelineblock* and replace

```
.sameline.block {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

with

```
.samelineblock > div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I now understand the selection and float much clearer.
However, I couldn't understand why my "footer-below" is located only on the width of "around-the-wed" instead of the whole footer.

Comment: To overcome this you need to set:  .samelineblock { overflow:hidden; }

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code in your css.

`.samelineblock .about-this-page,.samelineblock .around-the-web {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0 30px 0 0;
}`

Answer (score -1):

Use flexbox on your container `.sameline-block`. You can then add margin and/or padding and other styles to your flex children `.about-this-page` and `.around-the-web`.

```css
/*footer*/
footer {
  color:white;
  background-color: #c2b180;
}
.button-social {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sameline-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<footer>
  <div class="sameline-block">
    <div class="about-this-page">
        <h3>About this page</h3>
        <p>Made by Duy Ta</p>
    </div>
     <div class="around-the-web">
        <h3>Around the Web</h3>
         <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
         <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
         <a class="button-social" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-below">qlip © 
    <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>. All Rights Reversed
  </div>
</footer>
```